# Swing Trading Risk Management

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange

I want to start swing trading in Forex. I've been working on a demo account with £10000 and has had some success over the past months.

I'm wondering what is the correct lot sizes and deposit amount to start off with to ensure that I do things with as little risk as possible.

I've heard that per $100 you should use 0.01 Lot sizes but that seems a bit extreme? Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: I guess this is about *currency* "swing trading".

Comment: There's no hard fast set of rules to trading and opinions vary as to what the best approach is.  There are lots of web sites that offer information on the subject.  Here's one that discusses some of the variables: http://www.thepatienttrader.com/swing-trading-positions-sizing-guide/

Comment: @Fattie Yes currency swing trading.